# java to access webcam and pen tablet (standalone app vs applet)

Tags: java, applet, javafx-2

i need to develop in java an application that accesses local resources, mainly a webcam, and possibly a wacom bamboo pen tablet. It should take pictures and notes and then post them to a web server.

The ways i can think of are:

1. use applets
2. use some kind of standalone app created via JavaFx (or swing or similar)

Which way would you go about it? Are applets considered a viable/secure way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you intend to use 32-bits or 64-bits architecture?

Comment: 32 bit, what would be the difference if i used 64 (i mean related to the above issue)?

Answer (score 1):

I would go the standalone app route.  I always turn Java off in my browsers because I can never remember which specific version has security bugs.

If you build it as a desktop app I think you could quite easily convert it to be an applet later on if you wanted.